# ¿Cómo obtener valores RGB en la posición del mouse?

Tags: c++, winapi

Tengo un código en el cual quiero obtener los valores RGB en la posición `x` e `y`. ¿cómo podría hacerlo? Aquí está el código:

```
include stdio.h
include windows.h
include winuser.h

using namespace std;

int main(){


int x,y;



Sleep(1000);


POINT cursor;


GetCursorPos(&cursor);

x = cursor.x;
y = cursor.y;



HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);

if (hDC == NULL)
{

}

COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, cursor.x, cursor.y); En esta linea falla.

if (color == CLR_INVALID)
{

} 

unsigned r = GetRValue(color);
unsigned g = GetGValue(color);
unsigned b = GetBValue(color);


ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hDC); 
return 0;

}
```

Me da el siguiene error:

> [Error] ld returned 1 exit status.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola @Botters, ¿podrías indicar la línea exacta donde te da el error y el mensaje completo? Sería ideal que editaras la pregunta indicando cómo ha quedado el código después de unirlo con el de eferion, de ese modo los usuarios podrían ver si hay algún problema. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: gracias, amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que necesitas es el contexto de la pantalla:

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
if (hDC == NULL)
{
  // Error
}
```

Con esto y las coordenadas puedes recuperar el color en ese punto:

```
COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, cursor.x, cursor.y);
if (color == CLR_INVALID)
{
  // Error
}
```

Y ahora ya solo resta obtener las componentes del color en cuestión:

```
unsigned r = GetRValue(color);
unsigned g = GetGValue(color);
unsigned b = GetBValue(color);
```

Y ya está... para terminar el programa sin dejar cabos sueltos solo queda liberar los recursos que ya no necesitamos:

```
ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);
```

Comment: gracias por contestar, pero me sale este error : [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Botters ese error por si solo no dice nada... ¿has intentado averiguar en qué línea se produce ese error?

Comment: después de esta linea if (hDC == NULL)
   {
     // Error
   } el cursor cuando lo pongo encima aparece rojo

Comment: @Botters y qué versión de Windows estás usando?

Comment: windows 10 amigo

Comment: puse el codigo en otro documento y lo ejecuté solo y me salió este error: [Note] 'COLORREF color' previously declared here el error es de esta linea : COLORREF color = GetPixel(hDC, cursor.x, cursor.y);

Comment: @Botters no tengo muy claro qué estás haciendo porque este segundo aviso es porque has duplicado la declaración de `color`...

Comment: @Botters por otro lado... en el comentario de `Error` deberías abortar el proceso y, a ser posible, mostrar un mensaje de error personalizado. Si esos errores no aparecen es que hay alguna función que estás usando de forma incorrecta

Comment: disculpe confundí los errores, al separar el codigo que usted me dio y ejecutarlo me salió este error: [Error] 'cursor' was not declared in this scope

Comment: pero si lo ejecuto con mi codigo me sale:[Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Botters eso es porque esa variable la tienes declarada en tu código... esa variable y la llamada a `GetCursorPos` las tienes que mantener... aunque quizás, viendo lo verde que estás en C++, sería más conveniente que empezases leyendo un manual de C++. Y no lo digo por ofender sino porque si no tienes un nivel mínimo la frustración te va a acabar consumiendo

Comment: empecé a estudiarlo hoy, pero quisiera resolver esto del rgb